# Dynamic allocation as a parameter, so to speak?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Assume we have a vector of Cursor object pointers. A cursor object is constructed with a single int parameter. So will this syntax work?

```
vector<cursor*> cursors;
cursors.push_back(new cursor(4));
```

Or do I have to do it as:

```
cursor* tempCursor = new cursor(4);
cursors.push_back(tempCursor);
```

Comment: Your question clearly shows you haven't even tried.

Answer (score 1):

You will leak memory if you do this as you are stating and don't clean it up afterwards.

A better way would be to use a shared_ptr.

The code would look like this

```
cursors.push_back(std::make_shared<cursor>(4));
```

It's a little hard to understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish though.

As mentioned below in the comments by @cat-plus-plus, unique_ptr should be used unless you explicitly want the object shared elsewhere, the code then would look like the following:

```
cursors.push_back(std::unique_ptr<cursor>(new cursor(4)));
```

Comment: No, a better way is to use `unique_ptr`. `shared_ptr` should be used only when absolutely needed.

Comment: unique_ptr should be used when you want to only have a single owner of the object, it's not clear that's what he wanted in this case, hence the shared_ptr.

Comment: Shared ownership is the corner case, not unique ownership.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that you may not have tried this here's an explanation of what's going on:

when you create a new cursor object it returns a new cursor object.  When you use a push_back function it pushes an object back on a vector.  So, when you create a new object inside the push_back it evaluates that function which returns a new cursor which then gets pushed back.

Basically its all about return values and evaluations.

Answer (score 0):

It will work, but chances are pretty good that you're better off doing something else. Absent a really good reason to do otherwise, I'd consider making it a vector of cursors (instead of pointers to cursors). In this case, you can just do something like:

```
std::vector<cursor> cursors;

cursors.push_back(4);  // or cursors.emplace_back(4);
```

This generally improves programmer efficiency by automating memory management, and improves code efficiency by eliminating unnecessary levels of indirection.